# No animation during resizing Angular Material2 sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-animations

- Have a `mat-sidenav` (`opened="true"`) with `mat-nav-list`
- Each `mat-list-item` has a `mat-icon` and a `span`
- `mat-sidenav-container` has `autosize` directive

But there is **no animation during resizing** (collapse/expand) of `mat-sidenav`.

**HTML**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" [opened]="true" #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item (click)="isExpanded=!isExpanded">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>reorder</mat-icon>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Home</span>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Athlets</span>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>group</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Teams & Partnerships</span>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**CSS**

```
.example-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .mat-sidenav {
    background-color:#3a3636;
  }
  .mat-list-item {      
    color: #faf6f6;
  }
  .mat-list-item:hover {      
    color: #3a3636;
    background-color:#faf6f6;
  }
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isExpanded = true;
}
```

**If there is no inbuilt implementation for this in Angular Material2, how can I achieve the animation?**

Comment: Did you install Angular animations, as described in the docs? - https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-2-animations

Comment: @Und3rTow Yes. If I change `(click)="sidenav.toggle()"`, the whole `sidenav` is hiding with animation ( or delay)

Comment: Does any one have some idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hide the menu, here is a way to do it :

With animations states, you can simply use the style transform to translate your sidebar.

**animations.ts**

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';

export const hideAnimation =
  trigger('hideAnimation', [
    state('opened', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
    state('closed', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
    transition('* => *', [
      animate(500)
    ])
  ]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [hideAnimation]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  state = 'opened';

  toggleState() {
    this.state = this.state === 'opened' ? 'closed' : 'opened';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav [@hideAnimation]="state" mode="side" [opened]="true" #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item (click)="toggleState()">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>reorder</mat-icon>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
        <span>Home</span>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
        <span>Athlets</span>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>group</mat-icon>
        <span>Teams & Partnerships</span>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**EDIT**

To hide only the span and reduce the size of the sidenav, this can help you get closer to what you want to achieve :

**animations.ts**

```
export const menuAnimation =
  trigger('menuAnimation', [
    state('opened', style({ opacity: 1 })),
    state('closed', style({ opacity: 0, width: '0px', display: 'none' })),
    transition('* => *', [
      animate(500)
    ])
  ]);
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" [opened]="true" #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item (click)="toggleState()">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>reorder</mat-icon>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
        <span [@menuAnimation]="state">Home</span>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
        <span [@menuAnimation]="state">Athlets</span>
      </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>
        <mat-icon matListIcon>group</mat-icon>
        <span [@menuAnimation]="state">Teams & Partnerships</span>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Don't want to hide the full `mat-sidenav`. For that i could use `sidenav.toggle()`. Need to hide/show only the `span` elements. Putting `[@hideAnimation]` on span. Makes the text "Home" move left. But the whole `mat-sidenav` stays there.

Comment: Yeah that was close. But problem with `<h3>Dashboard</h3>`, which moves left when opening `mat-sidenav'`

Comment: It doesn't move when I test my code. It has to come from your css, but the animation is this one

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Will check it again